# Viewing MS Office document properties from command line?

Tags: scripting, microsoft-office, utilities

I'm looking for a way to view the properties (title, author, company, etc.) of Office documents from the command line, hopefully both the standard and custom ones.  Does such a utility exist?

(My intention is to write a script which lists the files in a directory hierarchy and displays information about them, including the properties.  All the other info I'm interested in is easy enough, I just can't see a way to get the properties.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DSOFILE.dll](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=224351) may hold the answer if you're using Windows. There is a discussions about it [here](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/5093/retrieving-the-summary-properties-of-a-file/)

Comment: Thanks, JS.  That .dll and the code snippets gave me a shove in the right direction and I managed to get what I needed.  Turned out be more work than I had expected when I started this but what I've got will do.

Comment: Glad to help, any chance of marking my answer 'up' :)

Comment: @user10807 It would be helpful (and conventional here) for you to explain your final answer in more depth, preferably as your own answer. Although given that it is now nearly a decade later, it is unlikely that you will remember what it was.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what your system is running. If you can run the GNU/Linux wv library and its applications then does wvSummary give some of the info you want?

The first few lines returned from wvSummary on a local .doc file were:

```
Metadata for Men.doc:
    Template = "Normal"
    Security Level = 0
    Created = 2009-02-28T17:37:00Z
    Last Saved by = "Administrator"
    Revision = "1"
    Number of Characters = 529
    Keywords = ""
    Subject = ""
    Generator = "Microsoft Office Word"
    Last Modified = 2009-02-28T17:47:00Z
    Creator = "Administrator"
    Number of Pages = 1
    msole:codepage = 1252
    Number of Words = 92
    Description = ""
```